# Unable to connect from remote ibeacon gateway device to Google Cloud IoT Core

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ibeacon, gateway, google-cloud-iot

I am trying to set up a beacon gateway against Google Cloud IoT Core with no luck at all.

I think the problem is that the beacon gateway does not support JWT auth, so I'm setting up a gateway with the ***association only*** auth method, as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/gateways/authentication#authenticating_over_the_mqtt_bridge).
I know it's the least secure method, but I see no way to generate a JWT.

Anyway, the thing is that I don't know how to link/bind my physical device to the device at the registry Cloud IoT Core.

This is what I have done so far

- I created Pub/Sub topics and its subscriptions

```
gcloud pubsub topics create publish 
     --project=${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}
gcloud pubsub subscriptions create publish-sub \
     --topic=publish \
     --project=${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}
```

- Created Cloud IoT registry, gateway and device

```
gcloud iot registries create eu-registry   \
     --region=${GOOGLE_CLOUD_REGION} \
     --event-notification-config=topic=publish  \
     --project=${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}

gcloud iot devices create ${GATEWAY_NAME}   \
     --region=${GOOGLE_CLOUD_REGION} \
     --registry=${REGISTRY_NAME}  \
     --auth-method=association-only   \
     --device-type=gateway \
     --public-key path=/path/to/rsa_cert.pem,type=rsa-x509-pem \
     --project=${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}

gcloud iot devices create ${DEVICE_NAME} \
     --region=${GOOGLE_CLOUD_REGION}   \
     --registry=${REGISTRY_NAME}   \
     --device-type=non-gateway   \
     --project=${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}
```

- Bound device to the gateway

```
gcloud iot devices gateways bind \
     --device=${DEVICE_NAME} \
     --device-region=${GOOGLE_CLOUD_REGION} \
     --device-registry=${REGISTRY_NAME} \
     --gateway=${GATEWAY_NAME} \
     --gateway-region=${GOOGLE_CLOUD_REGION} \
     --gateway-registry=${REGISTRY_NAME} \
     --project=${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}
```

*( in this case, device and registry are in the same region )*

I have read that "To enable the gateway to proxy device communications with Cloud IoT Core, have the gateway publish a QoS 1 /devices/{device_ID_to_attach}/attach control message over the MQTT bridge." [here](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/gateways/mqtt-bridge#attaching_devices_to_a_gateway), but I think I may had missed a step because I have no idea how to do that.

I have followed [this](https://services.google.com/fh/files/misc/iot_device_partner_integration_guide1.0.pdf) guide as well and created and additional gateway, with no luck neither

I have thought about checking the remote device logs but it's not possible because I have no keys for the OS.

In addition, these are the params at the ibeacon gateway I can set:

- **Service Access** :: mqtt
- **MQTT Type** :: SSL
- **MQTT URL** :: mqtt.googleapis.com:8883
- **Client ID** :: I have tried few names, like my Google project, the device name (pretty random) or the device ID
- **QoS** :: 1
- **User Name** :: random string (1)
- **Password** :: random string [ only for the JWT auth ] (1)
- **CA** :: GCP roots.pem [ from https://pki.goog/roots.pem ]
- **Client Certificate** :: rsa_cert.pem (2)
- **Certificate Key**   :: rsa_private.pem (2)
- **Publish Topic** :: publish

(1) as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge#configuring_mqtt_clients) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/gateways/authentication#authenticating_over_the_mqtt_bridge)
(2) auto generated

```
openssl rsa -in rsa_private.pem -pubout -out rsa_public.pem
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout rsa_private.pem -days 10000 -out rsa_cert.pem -subj "/CN=unused
```

I have to say that this configuration works with using a software gateway device that sends data, just because this software remote gateways generate a JWT key, so it's not the same case.

Any idea of what I left behind, or what am I doing wrong?
Thank you very much!!